# Dynamic definitions not working in ttabbox

Tags: floatrow, definition

I made a macro called `\uref` with some help from around here. It creates dynamic definitions that produce unique labels. If I call it with `\uref{first}` it returns a, and every subsequent call with the same label it returns a. If I call it with a new label, it returns b, and so on. It does this by checking if a definition exists, and if not, it creates it and assigns a letter based on a counter.

It works fine and dandy, except in the `ttabbox` command from `floatrow` that I use to make the captions and foot notes of my tables size well. If I use the same labels in the same order *before* the `ttabbox`, it works. So I suppose I could build an invisible table first with `\setbox0\vbox{\atable}`, but that doesn't satisfy my need to understand why this is happening. The point of using the macro anyway is for large tables were I might be changing the order of rows and label order change, I wouldn't want to load a long table twice.

Any insight on why this command is causing the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\newcounter{unilabIN}% my referene counter withIN each new instance
\newcounter{unilabOUT}% creates a new set of counters if incremented
\stepcounter{unilabOUT}% start at 1 -> a
\makeatletter
\newcommand\uref[1]{% my command "unique" referencer
  \@ifundefined{uni\alph{unilabOUT}lab@#1}{%if reference doesnt exist, ie. hasn't been used
    \stepcounter{unilabIN}\expandafter\xdef\csname uni\alph{unilabOUT}lab@#1\endcsname{\alph{unilabIN}}% create a label for reference
    % defines a command : uni&lab$  where & is group letter, and $ is the label name
  }{}%
  \csname uni\alph{unilabOUT}lab@#1\endcsname% call the label
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\atnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\uref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\providecommand{\atable}{
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
    Things & Applicable Things \\\hline
    Aardvark & \atnote{lookslikerat}, \atnote{fourlegs} \\
    Bat & \atnote{lookslikerat} \\
    Cheetah & \atnote{fourlegs} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}

Notes should print a, b, a, b

Mechanism doesn't work here (prints all a's)
\begin{table}[htpb]% htbp! settings
        \ttabbox% if no star use hanging
        {\caption{caption}\label{label}}%
        {\atable}%
\end{table}%

Mechanism works here IFF I comment out the above non working example
\atable%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclamer: I have never used `floatrow` so I might have misunderstood something about its inner working.)

You need to step the counter globally, no matter what the good intentions of `\ttabbox` are (see later for a detailed explanation). Basically you must replace the line

```
\stepcounter{unilabIN}
```

by

```
\global\advance\value{unilabIN}\@ne
```

or (more low-level)

```
\global\advance\c@unilabIN\@ne
```

Going back to your original MWE this means

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\newcounter{unilabIN}% my referene counter withIN each new instance
\newcounter{unilabOUT}% creates a new set of counters if incremented
\stepcounter{unilabOUT}% start at 1 -> a
\makeatletter
\newcommand\uref[1]{% my command "unique" referencer
  \@ifundefined{uni\alph{unilabOUT}lab@#1}{%if reference doesnt exist, ie. hasn't been used
    \global\advance\value{unilabIN}\@ne  % <=== THIS BIT HERE
    \expandafter\xdef\csname uni\alph{unilabOUT}lab@#1\endcsname{\alph{unilabIN}}% create a label for reference
    % defines a command : uni&lab$  where & is group letter, and $ is the label name
  }{}%
  \csname uni\alph{unilabOUT}lab@#1\endcsname% call the label
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\atnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\uref{#1}}}

\providecommand{\atable}{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
  Things & Applicable Things \\
  \hline
  Aardvark & \atnote{lookslikerat}, \atnote{fourlegs} \\
  Bat & \atnote{lookslikerat} \\
  Cheetah & \atnote{fourlegs} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \ttabbox
        {\caption{caption}\label{label}}%
        {\atable}%
\end{table}%

and see also\par\medskip
\atable

\end{document}
```

yielding as expected

[image]

### The origin of the problem

The macro `\ttabbox` has the purpose of setting the caption text (first mandatory argument) as wide as the natural width of its second mandatory argument (usually a `tabular`). As far as I can see it types its content three times: twice for measuring and one final time for the output.

In order to avoid "overcounting", `floatrow` redefines `\stepcounter` (and other things) by removing their `\global` character in the first two measuring passages, so that the counters are globally increased only once in the final typesetting. For example you can check that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\newcounter{mycntA}
\newcounter{mycntB}
\begin{document}
(\themycntA,\themycntB)
\begin{table}
\ttabbox{\caption{First}}
        {[Here a tabular]%
        \stepcounter{mycntA}%
        \global\advance\value{mycntB}1
        }
\end{table}
(\themycntA,\themycntB)
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

The counter `mycntA`, which has been increased by `\stepcounter`, has gone from `0` to `1`;  the counter `mycntB` has been manually increased *globally* and has gone from `0` to `3`.

### What's going on in your case

Simplifying *a lot*, your current code can be boiled down to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\newcounter{mycnt}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{%
   \@ifundefined{foo@#1}%
     {%
      \stepcounter{mycnt}%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname foo@#1\endcsname{\Alph{mycnt}}%
     }{}%
     \csname foo@#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\ttabbox{\caption{Caption}}%
  {%
   \begin{tabular}{cc}
   Left column & Right column \\
   \foo{bar} & \foo{baz}
   \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\foo{bar}, \foo{baz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, in the first measuring passage `\stepcounter` has only local effect: when TeX finds `\foo{bar}` it checks whether `\foo@bar` is defined; since it isn't, it steps the counter (*locally!*) and defines (*globally* because of `\xdef`!) `\foo@cnt` to expand to `A`. But since the increase is local it is restricted to the current cell (tabular cells always act implicitly as groups), so when `\foo` is called again in the second cell, the counter is again `0`! Thus `\foo@baz` is defined (globally) and assigned (again) the value `A`.

Now the second passage starts: however, this time the check for both `\foo@bar` and `\foo@baz` are positive! As a result, nothing is defined, and only the outputs `A` are printed. (Well, not really printed, since we are still in the measuring phase.)

And now the third passage starts: this would be the "real" one, where `\stepcounter` is really `\global` and would do what you expect; but the true branch if `\@ifundefined` is never executed! This explains why your counter is never really increased outside `\ttabbox`.

The definitions of `\foo@bar` and `\foo@baz` were global, so they persist of course also outside the `\ttabbox`.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much!

Comment: @likethevegetable Thx but don't be so quick in accepting. Maybe someone who understands `floatrow` better can give more insight. As I wrote in the very beginning, I never used `floatrow` and it is not exactly a "light" package to go through. I _think_ I understand what it's doing but I might be wrong.

Comment: Appreciate it. Do you see any drawbacks to using `\global` advance outside of the `ttabbox`? @campa

Comment: I mean if I use the function outside of a ttabbox, the global cs in uref won't be problematic?

Comment: Also, why is the @ necessary before the #1 in foo? Thanks

Comment: @likethevegetable I checked that this works also with `amsmath` environments. The `@` is not necessary, it's just a habit.